# Am I understant correctly about requestLegacyExternalStorage on Android 11 will be ignore

Tags: android, local-storage, android-11

[image]

I got the alert from google as the screenshot.

As I understand that is the flag requestLegacyExternalStorage will be ignore only on device running android 11+.

So with the Target version 29 the flag requestLegacyExternalStorage = true still valid and the storage access will be like it before for all android <=10, is that right?

The solution us only change the method Write File to App-external storage or Public Dir that provided by android 11. Is that right?

Or with the new update we must remove the flag requestLegacyExternalStorage completely from Manifest no matter which version.
Thanks.

Comment: if your app targets android 11+ you must use scoped storage is what its saying

Comment: You do not have to remove it. Leave it as it will continue to work on an Android 10 device. But it has no effect on an Android 11 device.